# The type 'Core.Entities.Product' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'IGenericRepository<T>'

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I am getting an error of

> The type 'Core.Entities.Product' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'IGenericRepository'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Core.Entities.Product' to 'Core.Entities.BaseEntity'.

Not sure if I am missing something or is my GenericRepository set up correctly

ProductController.cs:

```
namespace API.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IGenericRepository<Product> _productsRepo;
        private readonly IGenericRepository<ProductBrand> _productBrandsRepo;
        private readonly IGenericRepository<ProductType> _productTypesRepo;
        
        public ProductsController(IGenericRepository<Product> productsRepo, IGenericRepository<ProductBrand> productBrandsRepo, 
        IGenericRepository<ProductType> productTypesRepo)
        {
            _productsRepo = productsRepo;
            _productBrandsRepo = productBrandsRepo;
            _productTypesRepo = productTypesRepo;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<Product>>> GetProducts()
        {
            var products = await _productsRepo.ListAllAsync();
            return Ok(products);
        }
```

GenericRepository.cs:

```
using Core.Interfaces;
using Core.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Infastructure.Data
{
    public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
    {
        public readonly StoreContext _context;
        public GenericRepository(StoreContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<T> GetByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            return await _context.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
        }
        
        public async Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> ListAllAsync()
        {
            return await _context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

IGenericRepository.cs

```
using Core.Entities;

namespace Core.Interfaces
{
    public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
    {
        Task<T> GetByIdAsync(int id);
        Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> ListAllAsync();
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), (typeof(GenericRepository<>)));
    //get connection to database using connection string
    services.AddDbContext<StoreContext>(x => x.UseSqlite(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebAPIv5", Version = "v1" });
    });
}
```

Comment: Does `Product` inherit `BaseEntity`? Based on the error message, no it doesn't. You have explicitly constrained `T` to be or inherit `BaseEntity`.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you, solved my problem! Looks like i missed that

Answer (score 0):

My fix for this issue was inheitting BaseEntity to my Products Class

Products.cs:

```
namespace Core.Entities
{
    public class Product : BaseEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
        public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
        public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
        public ProductBrand ProductBrand { get; set; }
        public int ProductBrandId { get; set; }
    }
}
```